# How to find the destination point given a start point, distance and bearing?

Tags: postgis, spherical-geometry, cogo

If I have a starting point as well as distance and a bearing to the destination point, how can I find the coordinates of the destination point using PostGIS?

I'm looking for a PostGIS equivalent to this function:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#destPoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ST_Project()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html) function:

```
geography ST_Project (geography geog, float distance, float azimuth);
```

It returns a point "projected" from a start point using a distance in meters and bearing (azimuth) in radians.

You may need to first cast your geometry to a geography

```
goem::geography
```

convert your azimuth from degrees to radians

```
radians (azimuth)
```

and your distance to meters, if necessary. And remember to cast your resulting geography back to a geometry.

---

<sup>In my opinion, "project" is not the best name for this function, even though it makes sense literally (*pro-ject* = "throw forward"):</sup>

<sup>geomatics already has two or three existing phrases for this activity/calculation: *traverse* and *forward/direct problem*</sup>

<sup>*project* already means something else in geomatics: to transfer from the spheroid to the map/plane</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Didn't think to look in the geography functions.

Answer (score 3):

This is basically the same thing I said [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75407/how-to-create-linestrings-with-a-definite-angle-and-length-that-are-fixed-to-a/76066#76066), just modified to produce the end point instead of a line:

```
SELECT
    objectid,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Translate(ST_Rotate(ST_MakePoint(-1 * dist_field,0.0),
                                      radians(bearing_field)), ST_X(the_geom),  
                            ST_Y(the_geom)),ST_SRID(the_geom)) AS end_point_geom
FROM start_points
```

Where `start_points` is the table containing your starting points, `the_geom` in that table is the geometry column, `dist_field` is the distance field and `bearing_field` is the bearing field.

You may need to change the direction of the initial line (`ST_MakePoint(-1 * dist_field,0.0)`) to vertical (swap the coordinates/field name) depending on how you are measuring your bearing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this if `ST_Project` causes performance issues.